# JS onbeforeunload runs unconditionally to user's selected choice

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, onunload

I have a very simple code:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    console.log("closing");
    e.preventDefault();
    try { self.recorder.stop(); } 
    catch (err) { console.log(err); }
    return "custom message here";
}
```

What I need is to run the `recorder.stop()` only if the user presses yes, and actually unloads the page.
What I tried:

##### onpagehide

I found out that onpagehide actually runs `console.log("closing")` but not `recorder.stop()` for some reason. Possibly because it runs in the "terminated" state, and no async tasks can run in the terminated state.

##### onbeforeunload

The popup shows, and the code runs, however the code also runs if the user presses "cancel", and decides not to unload the page.

##### onunload

The code simply does not run.
I have a `console.log()` inside my `recorder.stop()` function, and tried it with the "keep logs" functionality from the inspector.

##### onvisibilitychange

This one looked promising, but I can't find the right state for it.

```
document.visibilityState === 'hidden'
```

Runs anytime I switch to another window, even without closing the previous one.

```
document.visibilityState === 'terminated'
```

Most probably won't work, for the same reason as `onpagehide()`

```
document.visibilityState === 'frozen'
```

Doesn't work, probably because the page does not freeze before terminating.

Comment: [Avoid "window.onunload", use pagehide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event). Follow the docs

Comment: @Andy Ray Thanks, I tried it but it seems to behave the same as onunload (it doesn't run)